# I have a problem with customising the header in React-navigation V6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I am trying to customise the header in React Navigation v6, and the problem is I have two header the default header and the custom header like here:

[image]

here is My code for the Stack navigation:

```
export const HomeNavigation = () => {
  const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackHomeParamList>();
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator headerMode="none" screenOptions={{headerMode :"none"}}>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Home',
          headerStyle: styles.header,
          headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitle,
        }}
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Play',
          headerStyle: styles.header,
          headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitle,
        }}
        name="PlayScreen"
        component={PlayScreen}
      />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Style :

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerTitle: {
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: colors.white,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: colors.secondary,
  },
  tabBarIcon: {
    marginBottom: -3,
  },
});
```

and I found in old versions that using `headerMode : "none"` will fix the this issue so I tried to add it everywhere and it wasn't fixing it to me, any clue what is the problem or maybe solution?

Comment: Hi Mohamed , did you try `options={{headerShown: false}}`

Comment: please let me know , you want to create custom headers or you want to customize the navigation headers. Thanks

Comment: @AnujSharma I wanna Customise the header and
`options={{headerShown: false}}  ` it removes the header

Comment: Where are you using this `HomeNavigation`?. Is it part of any other Stack?. Here is a  helpful link to get you started. 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#adjusting-header-styles

Comment: @nithinpp Yeah, 

I got it now thanks to you, the `HomeNavigation` is part of `TabNavigation` and this `tabNavigation` is adding the other header

Comment: One thing to note, from react navigation v6, It has headers by default in bottom tabs and drawer. Here's something to read upon that. https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2021/08/14/react-navigation-6.0/#headers-by-default-in-bottom-tabs--drawer.

Anyway, Glad that helped, Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 options={({ navigation }: any) => ({
          headerTitle: "Page Title",
          headerTitleStyle: { fontSize: 20 },
          headerTitleAlign: "center",
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Component/>
          ),
          headerRight: () => (
            <Component/>
          ),
         
        })}
```